# How to log in on mobile?

Tags: support, login, mobile-web

The log in option is not visible on Stack Overflow in Android mobile browsers. I have activated JavaScript.

How do I log in?

Comment: opera is not full supported browser for Stack Overflow, try another browser.

Comment: works for me on the stock android browser.  What version of android are you using?

Comment: @psubsee2003 i am using Opera Mini. I am using Android 2.3.5

Comment: @Lucifer I tried with the Dolphin browser as well. Dolphin provides the login options, but doesnt actually log u in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On mobile, first open the menu using the button in the top-right corner. That will reveal the login link.

Alternatively, perform any action that requires you to log in, and then just tap the link that is shown in "Please login or register to [...]".

[image]
[image]  
[image]

Note that some mobile devices, browsers or maybe even networks do not support the global auto-login feature. See [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) or use the [Network Login Troubleshooting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help) page.